# Python ta-lib - Order of time series

Tags: python, ta-lib

Stupid question when doing indicators in python based on a "series" of data.
Example ATR,SMA etc what should the ORDER of the series be ?

Latest data first or latest data last ?

Comment: It should probably be the latest data last